# Issue Import to Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket

I habe a problem wirh the Import of my issues to Bitbucket.

I have 3000 issues, but I can only import 1000. The import give e the following error message:

The error was: string indices must be integers

Comment: What's the source from where you are importing the issues? Are you importing your issues from GitHub to BitBucket or something like that?

Comment: I'm importing the source from Assembla to BitBucket.

Comment: Bitbucket Server (self-hosted) or Bitbucket Cloud (bitbucket.org)?

Comment: We use the Bitbucket Cloud